# Road blocked by stone arc?

Tags: tropico-4

In Tropico 4, Mission 5 there is a stone arc that leads to two mines (gold and iron).

Unfortunately I am unable to get there, because said arc seems to prevent any roads from being built underneath it!

[image: arc blocking road]

Is this a bug? (I sure hope so)

Is there any alternative way to get to the ressource fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed this too when I played that mission.  I believe it to be a bug.

My workaround was to build 2 roads and have a small gap under the arch.  Not ideal, and I'm not sure either road was ever actually used, but it worked.

Comment: Huh? Whats the point of the roads if they are not being used?

Comment: First, I'm not *sure* whether they were used. They may have been. Second, it looks nicer and for me reminds me what direction I built the thing in.

Answer (score 0):

I never even noticed the arch on that level, or if I did I must have assumed that I couldn't build under it. I think you'll find that there's another (much longer) route you can take, to the east of your starting town, then bearing south past the central volcano, and finally swinging round to the west to get to the mines. It was quite convenient for some of the deposits that turned up later, however.